# GIT: File rights lost on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions, git

I have a GIT repo on GitHub that I work with on both Windows and Linux. Here is what I observe:

```
(on Linux) git pull
(on Linux) I cannot save files. I change permissions, and make changes.
(on Linux) git push

(on Windows) git pull
(on Windows) I make some changes
(on Windows) git push

(on Linux) git pull
(on Linux) I *still* do not have the rights to change the files.
```

How can I have GIT always allow me to change the files in my repo on Linux?

Comment: This might be related to ntfs not having file permission, so when you push from windows it's not pushing permissions on the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more details. After "changing permissions" you *have* to do the "git add"/"git commit" (or simpler, "git commit -a") dance: git does register the permissions to the files.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the git repo under your home directory in linux

```
$>mkdir ~/source
$>cd ~/source
$>git init
$>git pull .....
```

Untested code, but this should point you in the right direction. You should have no perm problems under your home directory.

2) Do a sudo git pull, but I really don't recommend it.